# How to make a music using 'music' package?

Tags: r, package

I am reading to learn 'music' package in order to make a piece of music (any arbitrary music) from the following link:

```
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/music/music.pdf
```

This package has many functions and each of these functions has many arguments. I think for making music I do not need to use all the functions of this package. Could someone please give me an explicit example of making music using some functions of this package? (You can make any music you want).

Comment: Check out this vignette on the github page for the package [music vignette](https://egenn.github.io/music/music-vignette).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should play the first bar of "She'll be coming round the mountain"

```r
tune <- c("G5", "A5", "C6", "C6", "C6", "C6", "A5", "G5", "E5", "G5", "C6")
music::playProgression(tune)
```

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron. I have a question for you. How did you find c("G5", "A5", "C6", "C6", "C6", "C6", "A5", "G5", "E5", "G5", "C6")? How can I find such tunes of different music in order to play them in R?

Comment: @vahid I just know the scales and I know a few tunes. I didn't find the notes, I just knew the tune and what notes would make it.

Comment: Is there a function in R to find tunes (notes) of a music? Or is there a dataset in R of notes of some pieces of music?

Comment: @vahid no, I don't know of any such data sets in R. If you're looking for some simple tunes represented by the note names then you could start [here](https://takelessons.com/blog/easy-piano-songs-for-kids). If my answer helped you please consider marking it as accrpted. Thank you.

Comment: Yes @AllanCameron, you answered my question very well. I accept your answer.